# part of url in where clause in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have to put part of url in select query like

```
select* 
from tbl_name 
where column_name1 like employee 
   and column_name like questions;
```

there is a column name col_url and in that there are many site url but i have select those url which contain particular word likewise in this url of stackflow it is questions.

How can i do this i have written query above for example purpose .

[How can I create a blank/hardcoded column in a sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185743/how-can-i-create-a-blank-hardcoded-column-in-a-sql-query)

Comment: show a sample of your data  and of the expected result

Comment: i want to filter the table based on part of url like you see the url it have many word separated by backslash so i need to filter the based on that word only how can i do that

Comment: Please edit your question and show me a real sample (your value in db and the result you need)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer you expecting is this

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_name 
WHERE column_name1 LIKE employee 
   AND column_name LIKE questions
   AND col_url LIKE ('%select REPLACE(''col_url'',''\'','''')%')
```