# Q: CQL: add empty column to select result

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm trying to do a select with cql in which I want a new column to be added to the results with its cells set to some specific value, as it is done in sql in the following question: [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185743/how-can-i-create-a-blank-hardcoded-column-in-a-sql-query)

```
SELECT
  hat,
  shoe,
  boat,
  0 as placeholder
FROM
  objects
```

Is this possible?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: NO.. this is not possible in cassandra

Comment: Damn.. it would be a nice feature to have. Thanks!

Comment: [Here's](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11935) a proposal for adding arithmetic operations in CQL. It's not clear to me if we'll be able to write numbers directly in CQL or if the patch allows two columns to be summed. This feature will come out with Cassandra 4.0